# Has Hayao Miyazaki ever made an anime series or manga?

Tags: hayao-miyazaki

Hayao Miyazaki is a famous director of anime movies such as "Spirited Away" and "My Neighbor Totoro".

But has he ever made any anime series or manga besides movies? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Miyazaki is surprisingly prolific as a creator of manga. His best-known work in the medium is, of course, *Nausicaä of the Valley of the Wind*, on which his movie of the same name was based (for an interesting comparison of the different versions, see [here](http://www.utdallas.edu/research/spacesciences/hairston/nausicaamanga_film.html)). In a similar vein, he created a short manga for *The Wind Rises* a few years ago, in the leadup to the film. You can check out his [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayao_Miyazaki#Manga_career) for more details. [Reports suggest](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2013-11-09/ghibli-suzuki/hayao-miyazaki-is-drawing-samurai-manga) that Miyazaki is currently working on another manga, which will apparently be about samurai.

Miyazaki has never been the sole director of a television anime, but prior to his work on *Nausicaä*, he did extensive work on a number of television anime series (animation at first, and later, episode direction and co-direction), first at Toei, and later at A Pro and Nippon Animation (after that, of course, he founded Ghibli, and the rest is history). Prominent works in his oeuvre includes the first *Lupin III* anime and *Heidi: Girl of the Alps* (both co-directed with long-time collaborator and Ghibli co-founder Isao Takahata). Since *Nausicaä*, however, Miyazaki has done no further work on television anime.

Note: I forgot about [*Future Boy Conan*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_Boy_Conan), which is basically a Miyazaki show, technicalities of crediting notwithstanding (thanks, @JonathanVanMatre). For more details, take a look at @leonbloy's answer.

Comment: While it's technically correct to say he has never been sole director of a television anime, he was credited as director for all 26 episodes of *Future Boy Conan*, was co-credited as character designer, and was credited as storyboarder as well for the majority of the episodes. Technicalities aside, it's essentially a Miyazaki-helmed TV anime series, and likely the only one we'll ever see.

Answer (score 10):

Regarding anime series (manga answered by senshin):

Miyazaki has a single anime series of his own: [Conan, the boy of the future](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=899) ("Mirai Shōnen Konan" - "Future Boy Conan"). It's a TV series, from 1979, in 26 episodes. Miyazaki is not credited as the sole director (Takahata and Hayakawa directed some episodes), but he not only lead the direction but also the script and the characters. Sadly, it was not released in the US/UK, but it was seen on TV (dubbed) in several foreign countries, such as Spain, Italy, Saudi Arabia....

He also directed some chapters of the Lupin III anime series (before he directed the movie "Lupin III: Castle of Cagliostro"), and six of [Sherlock Hound](http://www.nausicaa.net/miyazaki/holmes/). And he worked as a relevant collaborator (mainly layout) with Tahakata's series [Heidi](http://myanimelist.net/anime/2225/Alps_no_Shoujo_Heidi) and [Marco](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074002/fullcredits).

Comment: He also helped do the concept for nadia: secret of blue water, with hideki anno, albiet not credited.